# Contact Us CMS Page

Tags: magento-1.9, email, contact-us

I have developed website on magento-1.9.2.3
We are not receiving any emails from contact us page even The form does exist and when we fill the forms it says "Successfully Submitted".

Comment: have you enter the admin email in admin panel at general->contacts?

Answer (score 1):

1. Login to admin panel
2. Goto admin-->system-->configuration-->General-->contacts
3. Enable Contact Us->Yes
4. Email options-->Send emails to-->(Enter your email id which you want to receive)

Answer (score 0):

If after setting your email to contact us form is not sending emails. Follow the instructions below to fix the issue.

This is caused by a change in the Magento core code.

Open the file:   **app/design/frontend/themedirectory/template/contacts/form.phtml**

If don't find the contacts folder here

Open the file:  **app/design/frontend/base/default/template/contacts/form.phtml**

Change the line:

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getFormAction(); ?>" id="contactForm" method="post">
```

To:

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('contacts/index/post'); ?>" id="contactForm" method="post">
```

Hope this will help you.